# Pip within virtual Enviroment

Tags: software-installation, python3

Background

#

My intention is to set up virtual environments using Python 3.7

I have already "burnt my fingers", on wrecking the py3.5.2 that Ubuntu16.04 depends on.

Assumptions

#

A) I understand that [apt-get install] even within a virtual environment is able to do a GLOBAL install which I DONT want.

B) There is no problem identifying the "pip" that comes from the local environment.

SPECIFICS

#

Since  &  look straight forward, I would like to know that installing via "pip" WONT give me that headache.

Comment: which environment manager are you using ?

Comment: i suggest https://anaconda.org/

Comment: Almost everything in Anaconda is also in the default Ubuntu repositories except for orange3 and jupyterlab notebook server extension.

Comment: Anaconda is what I intend to use, wherever Py37 dosnt give me an easy answer. Otherwise, Py37 has some sort of venv command which does the job directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip` is pre-installed in Python virtual environments (*virtualenv*) because sandboxing pip inside the Python virtual environment is one of the things a Python virtual environment is commonly used for. Everything that is installed by pip is installed inside the Python virtual environment locally by default, not globally the way apt installs packages in Ubuntu by default. Installing packages locally inside the Python virtual environment permits creating a Python virtual environment in your user's home directory and pip and pip3 commands will work in this Python virtual environment without sudo.